# Android - Prevent keyboard from dismiss while scrolling

Tags: android, layout, keyboard, android-edittext, scrollview

I have activity layout in below form

```
<relativelayout
<scrollview
<linearlayout
   <EditText1
   <EditText2
   <EditText3

 </linearlayout>
 </scrollview>
 </relativelayout>
```

whenever i tap on any edit text keyboard appears i need to achieve below tings

1. keyboard should disappear when clicked outside of edit text
   (working fine as am dismissing keyboard in dispatchTouchEvent()
   method).
2. Keyboard should NOT DISAPPEAR when user scrolls.
   (Currently it is getting disappear )

Please guide regarding this.

Edit -1 Code added which dismiss ke`

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    View view = getCurrentFocus();
    boolean ret = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

    if (view instanceof EditText)
    {
        View w = getCurrentFocus();
        int scrcoords[] = new int[2];
        w.getLocationOnScreen(scrcoords);
        float x = event.getRawX() + w.getLeft() - scrcoords[0];
        float y = event.getRawY() + w.getTop() - scrcoords[1];

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && (x < w.getLeft() || x >= w.getRight() || y < w.getTop() || y > w.getBottom()))
        {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}`
```

Comment: Add your source code also

Answer (score 0):

You should handle it based on the focus of edit text. I think this may be helpful:

```
 EditText txtEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);

 txtEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
               // code to execute when EditText loses focus
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes. Will try it. but what if user scrolled the view by touching the area outside of Edit texts. I don't want keyboard to get dismiss when user scrolls.

Answer (score -2):

Before handling this problem why don't you understand how views work when listeners are attached to them.

> Wrapping your head around the entire propagation of touch events (including the gesture) is imperative else while coding you’ll find yourself stumped by the behaviour of different ViewGroups (or Views) when attaching touch listeners to them with the hope that your code works as expected when they actually won’t.

[This](http://codetheory.in/understanding-android-input-touch-events/) article will not only help you with this question but for all your future endeavors with views and listeners.

Once gone through it maybe you can answer your own question.